# Sharing resources across agents, across processes in grinder

Tags: python, jython, shared-memory, grinder

Here is the requirement :

1. In simple words, I have a static dictionary(say dictionaryX) in a class (say ClassX in shared.py file) that needs to be shared across multiple agents and multiple processes in grinder.

How do I achieve this..?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the data in your dictionary known in advance, or is it derived programmatically during your grinder run?  Does your dictionary contain primitive or complex data types?

Comment: Actually no. It is prepared on the run..!! That is creating the whole issue as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches you could take:

- When your dictionary is calculated, store it to a common external location everyone can read.  (e.g. zookeeper, a shared network drive, a database, etc.)  Ideally this could happen somewhere in module-level code, so that it's not being done by each agent thread.
- Generate the data deterministically in each agent, so that they independently generate identical dictionaries.  You could then optionally have each agent/process only use a subset of the total data available, based on unique attributes such as the host name, thread number, etc.

Comment: Thank you Travis. The first part seems promising. I will check out the memcache or sqlite kind of storage structures. The second suggestion however is not feasible in my case as a unique data is being generated on the fly by the agents.